# android sdk error - AudioManager.isMicrophoneMute() always false

Tags: android, audio, mute

As the title states `AudioManager.isMicrophoneMute()` always returns false, no matter what.

*The setup:*

Manifest includes this permission because of an older bug that could be related to this. Old bug was about checking if headphones are used. Doesn't help, but doesn't hurt either.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />`

1. Initiate a call into the emulator from telnet.
2. Pick up phone
3. Check app - status `audioManager.getMode() == audioManager.MODE_IN_CALL` is `true`. Ok, we're good
4. Status check `audioManager.isMicrophoneMute()` is `false` - ok, we're still good
5. Switch back to phone and press the Mute button
6. Switch to app, check `audioManager.isMicrophoneMute()` and it's **still** `false` - no good. should be true.

So is this a broken API?  Or do I need some other permissions?  Or does this not work on Emulator??

Thank you.

Comment: Cross-posted as a bug with android SDK as well.  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=43947

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This now works in 5.x Lollipop.  Still doesn't work in 4.x.  Maybe Google just won't fix it for the older OS.

Answer (score 5):

I've made a small research and check the sources of Android. Actually, the problem is in the default Phone application in the file `packages/apps/Phone/src/com/android/phone/PhoneUtils.java`. Here is the function:

```
 /**
 * Internally used muting function.
 */
private static void setMuteInternal(Phone phone, boolean muted) {
    final PhoneGlobals app = PhoneGlobals.getInstance();
    Context context = phone.getContext();
    boolean routeToAudioManager =
        context.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.send_mic_mute_to_AudioManager);
    if (routeToAudioManager) {
        AudioManager audioManager =
            (AudioManager) phone.getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (DBG) log("setMuteInternal: using setMicrophoneMute(" + muted + ")...");
        audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(muted);
    } else {
        if (DBG) log("setMuteInternal: using phone.setMute(" + muted + ")...");
        phone.setMute(muted);
    }
    app.notificationMgr.updateMuteNotification();
}
```

You can see that if you click on Mute button Phone application checks the parameter `R.bool.send_mic_mute_to_AudioManager`, which is installed to `false` (I checked in the sources). Thus, in this case the state is to phone, which is an instance of GSMPhone class. This class communicates with RIL socket and send there appropriate request to setMute (`RIL_REQUEST_SET_MUTE`). Thus, nowhere on the path of the command the state of AudioManager is updated. Similarly, I do not see that AudioManager notifies to RIL when it change the state of the microphone.

Thus, if you ask AudioManager about the state of microphone it returns the default value (which is false). I do not know if this behavior is expected or is this a bug. You can ask question in the android-platform group and make a link to this question and bug.

Comment: Thanks, that's some slick detective work.  Do you know if I can just brute force overwrite `R.bool.send_mic_mute_to_AudioManager` in the config file or code to be `true`?

Comment: If you want to build your own Android image and use it you can simply change this value to false. If you ask me how to change this in a real device, then I do not know.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, not looking to build own image.  This would've been used in an app.

Comment: Awarding bounty, but not marking as answered since it points to the problem but doesn't resolve it. Thanks to everyone who reviewed my question and @Yury for providing an angle of attack.